# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS: cifs_mount failed w/return error -5

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nas, cifs

In my home network, I have a few very old hard drives in a NAS that I mount with the following fstab configuration:

```
//192.168.1.35/Volume_1 /mnt/Disk1 cifs _netdev,rw,guest,uid=128,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target 0 0
```

This has worked fine for years, until - as far as I can tell - today, when I used the software updater and Ubuntu rebooted. After rebooting, the system no longer mounts 2 of my 3 old disks (the third one is in a second NAS and works fine as far as I can tell).

When checking dmesg, the reported error is:

```
[  564.444927] Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers
[  564.444950] CIFS: VFS: Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers
[  564.444966] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.1.35\Volume_2
[  564.472906] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -5
```

I have tried googling the error code, but it only comes back with other error codes. I've tried mounting using different versions than 1.0, but then I get error 112 host is down. Mounting via the command line also does not work, but I assume there's no real difference between auto mounting and mounting via the command line as long as I use the same options. The error in dmesg is the same either way.

If I navigate to the network drive via the Ubuntu Files app, and mount the drive by right clicking and selecting 'mount', the drive mounts just fine, but not to the mount point that I need it to mount to.

I've reached my the end of my knowledge on Ubuntu/Linux quite a while ago, so I was hoping someone here could shed light on what the error -5 means or what could have changed that makes that this configuration started failing.

Comment: Work-around that *might* make data accessible, just to save it: boot from a Live Ubuntu USB, e.g. 20.04 LTS, and image the disks. Then it would be safe to try changes, such as repartitioning the disks with issues, checking SMART stats, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The data is reachable however. I can navigate to the network drives just fine, from Windows, Mac _and_ Linux. I just cannot mount the disks to the desired mounting point.